# Firebase performance monitoring crash ios app after start

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-performance

I am using firebase on our project for some time now. And we decide to implement performance monitoring. I updated all FB packages to the latest version and all works fine. After update, i added `"@react-native-firebase/perf": "^14.2.2"` install pods and set up android. Android works fine but ios have some issues.

When I open the ios app it loads and runs fine for 30 seconds and then freeze and I can catch this error in the Xcode log:

```
2022-01-20 12:32:31.885175+0100 APPNAME[473:51878] -[fir_7891ABC3-3A54-4945-8F53-592D0CAF4D03_GULNetworkURLSession _flex_swizzle_8d46847a_URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28003a2e0

2022-01-20 12:32:31.886164+0100 APPNAME[473:51878] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[fir_7891ABC3-3A54-4945-8F53-592D0CAF4D03_GULNetworkURLSession _flex_swizzle_8d46847a_URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28003a2e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1818a50fc 0x19a0ead64 0x1819820c4 0x18183a524 0x181839660 0x102ed4b74 0x102ecb254 0x102ed49d4 0x1820afe1c 0x105c446d4 0x105c463b4 0x105c56898 0x18185dd84 0x181817f5c 0x18182b468 0x19d3c338c 0x1841ce5cc 0x183f4cf70 0x102a11bec 0x105b11aa4)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[fir_7891ABC3-3A54-4945-8F53-592D0CAF4D03_GULNetworkURLSession _flex_swizzle_8d46847a_URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28003a2e0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any idea how to fix it?

package:

```
    "react-native": "0.64.1",

    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^14.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^14.2.2",
```

*UPDATE*

I tried downgrade firebase to the originally used version `13.1.0` and after then i added `perf` with this version and error is still present

Answer (score 0):

i was able to fix this with `use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.78'})`